# Error on uploading images with size greater than 1MB

Tags: php, laravel, image-optimization

I used to upload images on the server without any problem, but after I installed spatie larave-image-optimizer I ran into some problems. I can upload any image that is less then 1MB, but anything over will break it

I tried to console log or dump an error so that I can see what's going on, but I don't understand what the error message is telling me.

```
$validate = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'docs.*' => [
            'sometimes',
            'image',
            'mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg',
            'max:51200',
        ],
    ]);

    if ($validate->fails()) {
        return response(['error' => 'Error!'], 422);
    }

    if ($request->file('docs')) {
        foreach ($request->file('docs') as $doc => $image) {
            $image->storeAs(
                '/folder/' . $id , //I get this id from the params
                $image->getClientOriginalName(),
                'public'
            );
        }
    }
```

This route goes through the image optimizer middleware

```
    Route::middleware('optimizeImages')->group(function () {
        Route::post("url", "...Controller@store");
    });`
```

I get this error:

```
    exception: "InvalidArgumentException"
    file: "{app_path}\vendor\spatie\image-> optimizer\src\Image.php"
    line: 14
    message: "`` does not exist"
```

Why does the 1MB image uplod, but one that is 2MB+ not? And how do I fix this behavior?

Keep in mind that before installing this package everything worked. I uploaded many images that are 4MB+, but I need them opimized so I use my server's disk efficiently.

EDIT #1
Error if i don't use the middleware:

```
    exception: "RuntimeException"
    file: "{app_path}\vendor\symfony\var-dumper\Server\Connection.php"
    line: 63
    message: "stream_socket_sendto(): A request to send or receive data was 
    disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a 
    datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.↵↵"
```

Comment: Did you see the `package issue`? - https://github.com/spatie/laravel-image-optimizer/issues/67

Comment: I tried updating the sizes mentioned in that, but the error is the same...

Comment: try to delete the `muddleware` group for testing

Comment: I commented the middleware out and I get an other error: 

        `exception: "RuntimeException"
        file: "{app_path}\vendor\symfony\var-dumper\Server\Connection.php"
        line: 63
        message: "stream_socket_sendto(): A request to send or receive data was 
        disallowed because the socket is not connected and (when sending on a 
        datagram socket using a sendto call) no address was supplied.↵↵"`

Comment: @Joseph a added the error in the q, so it is easier to red

Comment: this package you installed make something wrong in your project delete this package from your composer file and delete your vendor folder then run `composer update`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

go to your `php.ini` file and change those

```
upload_max_filesize = 10M
post_max_size = 10M
```

after that make sure you restart your apache server

Comment: The error is the same. I even restarted my PC to make sure my apache server is restarted...

Comment: It solved it... I was changeing the php.ini in my windows, not in XAMP. I had no ideea that those were different. After I changed those values in XAMP it worked as expected. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

In your `php.ini` change values like -

```
memory_limit=32M
upload_max_filesize=24M
post_max_size=32M
```

Restart your server. Try with `composer update`. If not work, remove your `spatie/laravel-image-optimizer` and again install - `composer require spatie/laravel-image-optimizer` and then publish `php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Spatie\LaravelImageOptimizer\ImageOptimizerServiceProvider"`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Changind the `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` worked. I had to change them in XAMP, not in my windows' php.ini file. Now I just have to change up on the server and it should work.